# If element is set in C++ std::map?

Tags: c++, dictionary

How to find out if an element in std::map storage is set? 
Example:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

map<string, FOO_class> storage;

storage["foo_el"] = FOO_class();
```

Is there something like `if (storage.isset("foo_el"))` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (storage.count("foo_el"))
```

[`count()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/count) returns a number of occurrences of the item within a container, but a map can have only one occurrence of each key. Thus `storage.count("foo_el")` is 1 if the item is present and 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

Try `storage.find("foo_el") != storage.end();`.

Answer (score 1):

The std::map operator [] is nasty: It creates an entry if it does not exist, have a map::find first.

If you want to insert or modify

```
std::pair<map::iterator, bool> insert = map.insert(map::value_type(a, b));
if( ! insert.second) {
   // Modify insert.first
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the iterator when inserting a new key-value pair:

```
std::map<char,int> mymap;
mymap.insert ( std::pair<char,int>('a',100) );
std::pair<std::map<char,int>::iterator,bool> ret;
ret = mymap.insert ( std::pair<char,int>('a',500) );
if (ret.second==false) {
    std::cout << "element is already existed";
    std::cout << " with a value of " << ret.first->second << '\n';
}
```